# $n-$ linear function and subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Lets $V_1,V_2, \dots, V_n$ and $W$ vector spaces over a field $F$ and let $f: V_1 \times V_2\times \cdots \times V_n \to W$ a $n-$linear function. Show that if $\dim W>1$, then $Im(f)$ is not necessarily a subspace of $W$.

I don't know which condition does not hold. I need to build a counter-example, can you give me a tip?

Comment: You can try to prove the condition, and probably you'll be stuck with one of them.